# How to parse json and create table with it?

Tags: json

I'm having a response like this :

```
var response = {"items":[ {"id":"-1", "name":"Locate unit"},
                          {"id":1047, "name":"unit_1"},
                          {"id":1048, "name":"unit_2"}],
                "label" :"name",
                "identifier" : "id"};
```

What I would like to do is to have the table Unit and ID ( Unit will be the column of name and ID column of id).
I'm basing on http://jsfiddle.net/rrzZU/235/. Do I have to make operations on my response ? I have parsed it like this :

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + response + ']')
```

Is it normal that when I want to see the value with

```
alert(jsonObj)
```

it's returning

```
Object object
```

I'm confused since many JSON data used to create table are like this :

```
var json = [{"User_Name":"John Doe","score":"10","team":"1"},
            {"User_Name":"Jane Smith","score":"15","team":"2"},
            {"User_Name":"Chuck Berry","score":"12","team":"2"}];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Object object" in alert means that you have successfuly parsed your json to a JS object. To see what is in your object use console.log() and open the console. But, on the other hand, the "Json" you put in your 'response ' variable is actually already a JS object

Comment: So I can use my response variable to fill a table without doing any other operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly your response object to display a table, a quick example :

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + response.items[i].id + '</td><td>' + response.items[i].name + '</td></tr>';
```

Check the result on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa2xctx4/)

Cheers